# difficult to install libreoffice on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, libreoffice

I tried to install LibreOffice with the following command:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install LibreOffice_5.1.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
```

But I got this, do you know how to fix this problem?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package LibreOffice_5.1.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'LibreOffice_5.1.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'LibreOffice_5.1.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz'
```

Comment: You are being overly specific as to what you are telling it to install.  See my answer below - it is much simpler to let it figure out the version numbers and all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You should extract `LibreOffice_5.1.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz` and install whatever deb package in it.

e.g `tar xvf LibreOffice_5.1.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz && dpkg -i $(find . -name '*.deb')`

Answer (score 1):

With Kali Sana 2.0, I just used these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gnome
```

Word to the wise:  Make sure you are not always logged in as root.  Create a user name for your day-to-day operations.

Kali is not the ideal version of Linux to use for general office-like computing, but I have used it that way for a long time and find it very convenient.